# Use multiple VLOOKUPS in one cell to return 1 value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I currently have 3 different vlookups I'm using to try and find 1 master number.  There are instances where I could find this number based off of 2 different unique numbers or a persons name.  I'm able to put multiple vlookups in one cell and have it return all hits, but that's not what I'm wanting.

I want it to pull off of the first number if possible, if not, pull from the second number and so on so that I'm left with either one number or a blank.

```
Master #     Unique #1       Unique #2    Name
12345        526             9963         George Lucas
54321        527             7145         Harry Potter
```

Comment: Have you tried putting them in `if`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept is:

```
=IFERROR(vlookup(..1st..),
         IFERROR(vlookup(..2nd..),
                 IFERROR(vlookup(..3rd..), <what if no match>)))
```

`IFERROR` will return the first argument if it is not an error, and if it is an error, the second.  `VLOOKUP` throws an `#NA` error if it doesn't find, so it works perfectly here; sort of like `COALESCE` in SQL-like languages.

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm.  I appreciate your help, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I realise OP has accepted an answer, but I interpreted the Q in a different way. Considering `to try and find 1 master number`, `based off of 2 different unique numbers or a persons name` and the sample data (where `Master #` is at the extreme left), VLOOKUP may not work.

If to search for the matching `Master #` based off any of `Unique #1`, `Unique #2` or `Name` I suggest:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,B:B,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,C:C,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,D:D,0)),"")))
```

where `F2` is assumed to contain the search term and `Master #` is assumed to be in A1, etc.
The principle however is exactly the same as the accepted A, since =MATCH used in this way will also return an error where an exact match is not found.